# Countdown timer or Pomodoro for Android that is automatically restarted but asks to be dismissed

Tags: android, time-management, timer

Android's timer is one button for dismiss and one button for reset. Sometimes, I forget to press reset.

Please suggest a countdown timer app (for Android) that automatically restarts but asks to be dismissed.

For example, I want a timer to go off every 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, it should keep ringing or vibrating until I dismiss it. However, even though I don't dismiss it, it should have already restarted.

I tried Brain Focus, a Pomodoro-based app (I made break and work the same time), but it doesn't ask me to dismiss so sometimes I don't notice that the timer goes off.

---

If possible:

1. Might there be an app that (automatically restarts but asks to be dismissed and) **tracks how much time has passed**? For instance, every time my timer goes off (eg 5 min), I might draw a stick. So, I'm hoping that there's an app that would do that for me: Draw a stick or indicate how much time has passed.
2. Might there be an app that (automatically restarts but asks to be dismissed and) **has a countdown** or anything that **indicates how much time is left**?

Comment: Like the old countdown - repeat function lots of Timex watches still  have?

Comment: @Xen2050 What do you mean? Is there an app version? XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I Can't Wake Up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kog.alarmclock&hl=en) - The creator is pretty cool.

If it's for example 7:05am, you can set the alarm to 7:10am and then have it vibrate and snooze every 5 minutes. Snoozing an alarm is equivalent to dismissing a timer and then restarting it only more efficient.

Edit: Actually you can use I guess any alarm clock such as the Android Timer, but one difference is that it might be easier to snooze and so if the phone is one's pocket, then the phone might [pocket snooze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_dialing)